# How could I use the except function with a for loop

Tags: python, validation, input

When there is a wrong answer, I would like a preset message for all the operators to be displayed.

Maybe something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_ans = int(input()) 
    except ValueError: 
        print ("That is not a valid answer")
        continue 
    else:
        break
```

but in a `for` loop.

My aim is to ask numerical questions then save to a file.

First, I need to ask the user what maths class they are in, then ask 10 randomly generated questions.

```
#Imports
import random
from time import sleep

#List & Definitions#
operators = ("-","+","X")
score = 0
QA = 0 

#Intro#
print ("Hello and Welcome")
print ("What is your name?")
name = input ()
print ("Do you want to Play (Yes/No)?")
choice = input()
if choice =="Yes":
    print ("Excellent")

if choice == "No":
    print ("Okey, bye...")
    end()
    quit()

print ("Please input your class")
cn = input ()
print ("Let's start the quiz!")
sleep(2) 

#Asking Questions
for QA in range (0, 10): 
    numb1 = random.randint(1,10)
    numb2 = random.randint(1,10)
    randOp = random.choice(operators)
    #Addition
    if randOp == "+" :
        print (str(numb1) + "+" + str(numb2))
        answer = numb1 + numb2

        print ("Please input your answer")
        UserAns = int(input ())
        if UserAns == answer :
            print ("well done that was correct")
            score = score + 1
        if UserAns != answer: 
              print("that's wrong")

        else:
            print ("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")

    #Subtracting        
    if randOp == "-" : 
        if numb2 > numb1 :
          print (str(numb2) + "-" + str(numb1))
          answer = numb2 - numb1
          print ("Please input your answer")
          UserAns = int(input ())
          if UserAns == answer :
              print ("woah again Correct")
          if UserAns != answer: 
              print("that's wrong")


              score = score + 1
        elif numb1 > numb2 :
            print(str(numb1) + "-" + str(numb2))
            answer = numb1 - numb2
            print ("Please input your answer")
            UserAns = int(input ())
            if UserAns == answer :
                  print ("Correct :) ")
                  score = score + 1
            if UserAns != answer: 
              print("that's wrong")

    #Multiplication
    if randOp == "*" :
        print (str(numb1) + "X" + str(numb2))
        ans = numb1 * numb2
        sleep(1)
        print ("Please input your answer")
        UserAns = int(input ())
        if ans == UserAns :
            print ("Correct")
            score = score + 1
        if UserAns != answer: 
              print("that's wrong")    

    #Displaying Score
    QA = QA + 1 
    if QA == 10 : 
        print ("Your score is " + str(score) + " out of ten")

#Saving & Writing to File
savePath = "Results\Class " + str(cn) + "\\" + name.lower() +".txt"
file = open(savePath, "a")
file.close()
file = open(savePath, "r")
if file.read() == "":
    file.close()
    file = open(savePath, "a")
    file.write(name + "\n\n")
    file.close()
file.close() 
file = open(savePath, "a")
file.write(str(score))
file.write("\n") 
file.close()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second snippet of code?

Comment: Remove it; it is unneeded.

Comment: How is this related to javascript? And are you basically wanting to do input validation and handle the case that the user inputs "abc" instead of a number? Is there something in particular about the approach in your first code-snippet that's not working? Help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just make  better input functions..

```
def input_with_choices(prompt, choices):
   while True:
      choice = input('{} (choices are: {}) '.format(prompt, ','.join(choices)))
      if choice in choices:
         return choice
      else:
         print("That's not a valid choice.")
```

and

```
def input_int(prompt):
   while True:
      try:
         return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
         print("That's not an integer.")
```

etc.

Then you can use those to validate your input in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very understandable, however, what I think you are looking for is this:

```
accepted = False
while not accepted:
    try:
        UserAns = int(input())
        accepted = True
    except:
        pass
```